Small sample MLE vs OLS efficiency
MLE estimates are asymptotically efficient. Both MLE and OLS estimates are asymptotically normal and for many distributions their limiting variances coincide (information for one observation being the reciprocal of its variance in such cases). So at least from large sample theory I see no clear reason to prefer one over the other in that scenario. Now, intuitively it seems clear to me that, assuming the probability model is right (and is not normal), MLE should be more efficient for small samples too. Are there any known results in that regard?

MLE for which likelihood?

I'm not sure about what you ask. In my question I'm assuming I have the right model, so that would define the likelihood. Also consider non normal examples so as to make the question interesting. Then if asymptotics are the same, is there any reason to prefer MLE? (One more comment: perhaps in cases like that when asymptotic variances coincide, both estimates will be formally the same, maybe the only cases are of the form avg(x) for ML and LS, like in binomial, poisson, etc. so my question becomes irrelevant)

Say I want to estimate the parameters of a gamma distribution from a sample. I know how to use MLE for that.  How are you using OLS for that case? What about a Weibull? Or a uniform on $(\theta-\phi,\theta+\phi)$? If you don't mean to include these examples, what class of models do you intend?

Something I find problematic about this is how to treat an OLS estimate of something like $\sigma^2$ of $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, (even for known $\mu$).

I think there is a misunderstanding about the point of the question. Granted, there are many cases in which it's clear what the MLE is but there may be no meaningful way to use OLS. But the scope of my question are just those cases where both estimates exist and asymptotics are the same (i.e. limiting variances coincide with the CRB). I've also the suspicion that in those cases both estimates formally coincide, which may render the question uninteresting. But I've not given this a proper thought.

Do you specifically mean a regression where you compare the estimator that arises from minimizing the sum of squared residuals vs the estimator that comes from maximizing the likelihood, such as estimating the coefficients of a logistic regression by minimizng the square loss (Brier score) vs maximizing the Binomial likelihood (the latter of which is more common)?

Perhaps by "OLS" your intention was to refer to "Method-of-Moments" estimation?
